# FileUpload Control For DevExpress Windows Form

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I am new to DevExpress WinForms , Can any one tell what is simple way to use FileUploader control .
  I want to select image from File Dialog box and add it to PictureEdit.

Please Help!!
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Devexpress does not provide file upload control ( [See This](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q215196)),so that leaves you using native file uploader in your code.

A simple code would be

```
    // Create OpenFileDialog
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
    dlg.Filter = "image Files|*.jpg";

     Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();
     if (result == true)
     {
      this.pictureEdit1.Image = Image.FromFile(dlg.FileName) // Not tested this one
     }
```

Hope this helps